# iOS - "This class is not key value coding-compliant" when using associations?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, exception, key-value-coding

I have the following classes declared in my iOS application...

```
@interface UserRegistrationRequest : BaseServiceRequest

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *username;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *password;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *secretQuestionID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *secretQuestionAnswer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UserProfile *profile;

@end


@interface UserProfile : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *emailAddress;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *lastName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData *profileImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *dateOfBirth;

@end
```

As best as I can tell, these classes should be key-value coding compliant.  However, when I run the following code...

```
NSString *propKey = @"profile.firstName";
NSString *propVal = [self.registrationRequest valueForKey:propKey];
```

I get an exception saying...

```
[<UserRegistrationRequest 0xb6187f0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key profile.firstName.
```

Any idea why this is happening or what I should be looking for in troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use :

```
NSString *propVal = [self.registrationRequest valueForKeyPath:propKey];
```

Comment: That was it!  Can't believe I missed that.  Thanks!